# Do a branch and another branch created off it inherit changes from each other?

Tags: git

The followings are my observations:

- When I make unstaged changes to some files on a branch (without running `git add` or `git commit` afterwards) and then create a new branch by `git checkout -b newbranch`, the new branch will also "inherit" my changes from the original branch.
- When I am on a branch and then create a new branch, and make unstaged changes to some files on the new branch, and switch back to the original branch by `git checkout originalbranch`, the original branch will also "inherit" my changes from the new branch.

I am not sure if my observations are correct.

If my observations are correct, they don't make sense to me, because when we create a branch off another branch, we usually want to do separate work on them. If one branch inherits changes from the other branch, the work that we do on a branch will not be separated from the other branch. So why is the "inheritance"?

Comment: Can you pretty please with sugar on top stop adding "Thanks." to all your posts? I've pointed you to [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/) plenty of times already. While you're at it, go read [ask] and share your research with every question you post. An awful lot of your question can be answered by putting the title in your favorite web search engine. If you did that, and didn't understand what you find, then show what exactly you didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

> So why is the "inheritance"?

Git doesn't store the current working directory (i.e. the changes) in a branch, neither does every branch have its own staging area. Both are "global" to the git repository. So when you switch to another branch git has the choice of just ignoring all changes and deleting them or to try to apply them onto the branch you are switching to. Since git doesn't want to delete your work without you explicitly asking for it, git defaults to keep them and reapply them onto the other branch. You could of course commit or stash them, then you'd have the clean branch after checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a [graph, in the computer science sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)), meaning commits are nodes connected to each other. Branches are just flags on a node. For example, let's say you have 3 commits in master with the IDs A, B, and C.

```
A - B - C [master]
```

master is a flag pointing at commit C. When you make a new commit, D, it moves with it.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
```

When you make a branch, like `git branch feature`, it adds a new flag pointing at the current commit.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
              [feature]
```

When you commit to feature, master remains at D.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
             \
              E [feature]
```

When you commit to master, feature remains untouched.

```
A - B - C - D - F [master]
             \
              E [feature]
```

So you see, branches are actually branches. master and feature are referred to as "branch heads" because they point at the head of a branch. You can have multiple branch heads pointing at the same commit.

feature "inherits", or rather shares, A, B, C, and D with master because of the layout of the graph. There's ***nothing*** about A, B, C, or D which makes them owned by a particular branch. They're just ancestors of both the feature and master branch heads because of how the graph is laid out.

---

> *When I make unstaged changes to some files on a branch (without running git add or git commit afterwards) and then create a new branch by git checkout -b newbranch, the new branch will also "inherit" my changes from the original branch.*
>
> *When I am on a branch and then create a new branch, and make unstaged changes to some files on the new branch, and switch back to the original branch by git checkout originalbranch, the original branch will also "inherit" my changes from the new branch.*

"Inherited" is the wrong word. More like "left alone" because the two branches point at the same commit.

There is only ever one working directory and only one staging area. When you checkout a new commit, Git has to change the working directory to match the new commit and clear the staging area. If there's modified files sitting in the working directory or staging area, it will refuse to blow those changes away.

```
$ git checkout some-branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    some-file
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

But what you're describing is a special case. Since `newbranch` is brand new it is pointing to the same commit as the old branch. Checking it out doesn't change the files in your working directory. So the changes in your working directory and staging area are left alone.

In that special case, all the checkout does is switch which branch head will move when you commit.